# cannot set 2560x1600 resolution for Samsung S32D850T monitor from Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, hdmi

I  just bought a new Samsung S32D850T monitor hoping to get 2560x1600 resolution from my Dell Inspiron laptop. The laptop has HDMI and VGD ports. Is there any way to get that resolution (a new HDMI cable/a HDMI to DisplayPort adaptor) or I just need to return the monitor?

I have Windows 10 and in the display adaptors I see:
Intel HD Graphics 3000
NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M

Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem adding a custom resolution 2560x1440 in NVIDIA Control Panel. I had to select CVT Reduced Blank in order to see clear image on the screen. I decreased the contrast and now the new monitor shows the image as the old Samsung 24'' one showed.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)